# Function Payable

Tags: contract-design

I am learning to make a smart contract erc20
can anyone explain what this function means?

```
function () external payable {
    getTokens();
}

function getTokens() payable canDistr  public {
    uint256 tokens = 0;

    require( msg.value >= minContribution );

    require( msg.value > 0 );

    tokens = tokensPerEth.mul(msg.value) / 1 ether;        
    address investor = msg.sender;

    if (tokens > 0) {
        distr(investor, tokens);
    }

    if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
        distributionFinished = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A whole bunch of in-line commentary ...

```
function () external payable { // only callable from outside. accepts ETH.
    getTokens(); // invoke getTokens()
}


function getTokens() payable canDistr  public { // accept ETH from anyone is canDistr (defined elsewhere)
    uint256 tokens = 0; // unsigned (positive) large integer. Not necessary to initialize =0

    require( msg.value >= minContribution ); // reject if ETH sent is below minContribution set elsewhere

    require( msg.value > 0 ); // reject if 0 ETH received (redundant?)

    tokens = tokensPerEth.mul(msg.value) / 1 ether; // computer exchange rate with SafeMath multiplier and convert WEI to ETH. Suspect, in that the token may also have divisibility. 
    address investor = msg.sender; // waste some gas. no obvious reason for this

    if (tokens > 0) {
        distr(investor, tokens); // distr defined elsewhere. could be a log, more likely tries to distribute tokens
    }

    if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) { // if we are sold out ... 
        distributionFinished = true; // set a flag. probably related to canDistr
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions in your block of code.

The first function is a [fallback function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#fallback-function), which automatically gets called whenever someone initiates a transaction with the contract and does not specify a function or specifies a function which does not match any of the functions available; hence "fallback". We know it is the fallback function because the function does not have a name.

The fallback function in this situation is:

- [`external`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters): which means it can be called by other contracts
- `payable`: which means the function can accept ether (otherwise the function would reject any transaction that sends ether)

Finally, the fallback function simply calls the `getTokens()` function.

The `getTokens()` function basically checks that the user has sent ether, which is more than the minimum contribution, and then will calculate how many tokens the user should get based on the amount of ether they sent. There is a function modifier (`canDistr`) on `getTokens()` which (we assume) checks whether the distribution is finished, and will stop the function from working after that time. Distribution is marked as finished when `totalDistributed >= totalSupply`.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I think this is a function to withdraw funds from the smart contract to the wallet owner. haha

Comment: Yeah, that is not accurate. This function is all about converting ETH into a token (which I assume is defined by other code in the contract)

Comment: I found a withdrawal function like this, how it works ?:

Comment: Before you open a new question to ask this, I recommend you try your hand at a simple contract development tutorial which can hopefully teach you some Solidity and help you understand what it going on in other contracts. Try this: https://cryptozombies.io/